# problema al imprimir una lista en un ViewBag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

Tengo un controlador donde traigo una lista de una api, todo eso funciona.

Mi idea es que solo los `id` de esas listas se muestren en mi vista, y el cliente pueda seleccionar uno de estos, pero el `viewbag` que uso para pasar los `id` de la lista no funciona.

Este es el código de mi controlador

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Crear()
    {
        List<string> idProvedores = new List<string>();

        foreach (var id in await servicioProducto.ListaProvedores())
        {
            idProvedores.Add(id.Cedula);
        }


        ViewBag.listaProvedor = idProvedores;

        return View();
    }
```

Posteriormente en mi vista imprimo los id así.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <option disabled selected>Seleccione El id del provedor</option>
                    <select name="idProvedor" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.listaProvedor"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
```

Me sale este error y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que el error es porque debería usar un `IEnumerable` y no un `List`, pero aún así no me funciona, entonces no sé cómo pasarle todos los `id` de dicha lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El asp-items del select te pide una lista de SelectListItem, esta lista la creas usando la clase SelecList. Además necesitas una lista que tenga un par de valores (para el text y el value)

Algo así:

```
ViewBag.listaProvedor = new SelectList(idProvedoresroles.Select(x => new { Text= x, Value=x }), "Value", "Text");
```

El primer argumento es la lista, el segundo es el nombre de la propiedad que hace de ID, y el tercer es el nombre de la propiedad que hace de Text

Existe un 4to argumento para indicar el seleccionado por default

Otra solución es hacer esto

```
<select name="idProvedor" class="form-control">
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.listaProvedor as List<string>)
    {
      <option label="@item" value="@item"></option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: ok gracias me funciono la segunda forma, donde hago el foreach , pero tengo una duda eso solo es para mostrar, pero como capturo ahora el id ? al menos yo usaba el select asp-for="provedor.Cedula" , se supone que ese id se guarda en la cedula del provedor pero nose como capturarlo, me das una ayuda

Comment: a no perdon estaba facil solo era cambiar el name a la variable que guardaria ese dato y ya jeejje muchas gracias de verdad que tengas buen dia